# How to add an item to a custom list in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am facing a small problem, I cannot add an item to my custom list.

```
Future<KitchenProducts> createAlbum(String barcode) async {
final http.Response response = await http.post(
'https://mysite',
headers: <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
  'barcode': barcode,
}),
);

// Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
print(response.body);
return compute(parseResponse, response.body);
}

KitchenProducts parseResponse(String responseBody) {
final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

return parsed.map<KitchenProducts>((json) => 
KitchenProducts.fromJson(json));
}
```

I am sending an http request and I get some information that I want to add to the list.
My list:

```
List<KitchenProducts> products = [];
```

Function for adding an item to a list:

```
await createAlbum(barcodeScanRes).then((value) {
  products.add(KitchenProducts(code: value.code, name: value.name, weight: value.weight));
}).catchError((error) {
  print(error.toString());
});
```

As a result, I get the error:

> Exception: type 'List<KitchenProducts'> is not a subtype of type 'KitchenProducts'

And my model:

```
class KitchenProducts {

String code;
String name;
double weight;

KitchenProducts({this.code, this.name, this.weight});

factory KitchenProducts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return KitchenProducts(
  code: json['code'],
  name: json['name'],
  weight: json['weight'],
  );
 }
}
```

Tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createAlbum` function is already returning a list. Your `products` list is expecting a single `KitchenProduct` at each index, but you're trying to add a list of `KitchenProducts`. I suggest printing the return value `createAlbum` or stepping through it in the debugger to see exactly what it's returning. You likely need to iterate through the maps in the list to pull out the individual products, then add them to the list.